# Show series is conditionally convergent

Tags: real-analysis

Show that

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}{(-1)^n}/(n)^{1/2}{}$$ is conditionally convergent.

My attempt:

By definition of conditionally convergent, I need to show that 1) $\sum^\infty_{n=1}{(-1)^n}/(n)^{1/2}{}$ converges but 2) $\sum^\infty_{n=1}{|(-1)^n}/(n)^{1/2}{}|$ 
diverges.

By the alternating series test $b_n= 1/(n^{1/2})$ so $
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n= 0$ and $b_n$ is decreasing. Thus, I showed 1). I am not sure how to show 2).

Comment: What can you say for sure about the sum of the absolute values of the first $k$ terms of the series, relative to, say, $\sqrt{k}$?

Comment: Hint: direct comparison test and harmonic series.

Comment: are you saying that (1/n^.5) behaves like (1/n) so it diverges by comparison test?

Comment: @combostudent not exactly, but the direction is right.